# Pulling data from CRM System with Inputrange - mismatched lines

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have built a CRM System on Google Sheets and I am currently facing an issue with the mastersheet. The mastersheet is pulling data from other spreadsheets within the same document. The issue I am facing is that I would like the data to go on to the next available line at the bottom of the mastersheet page, instead of being put underneath the last entry from that particular sheet.

You can find the code I have used below:

`={FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Customer Data'!B:B"),LEN(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Customer Data'!B:B")));FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'17 June 2017 M&G Bookings'!B2:B"),LEN(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'17 June 2017 M&G Bookings'!B2:B")));FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Talent Agency - General Details Request form'!Q2:Q"),LEN(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Talent Agency - General Details Request form'!Q2:Q")));FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Performer Database'!P2:P"),LEN(IMPORTRANGE("1c47hRszG3jZf7SPj5pxtabmsw3tmR11ETx3hcEKue2w","'Performer Database'!P2:P")))}`

Can anyone please help me with this?
Timestamp goes to column A

Comment: What data do you want to go the next available line?

Comment: Every new data input.

Comment: Has your data a column with timestamps?

Comment: There are two: one marking the day the data was added, and another marketing when it was last updated.

Comment: Add that to the question indicating which columns has timestamps.

Comment: I have updated the main question. It’s column A

Answer (score 0):

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and it's ORDER BY clause could be helpful but you should add the timestamp column to your formula in order to use it to sort.

Comment: We have added the timestamp column but we don't know what code we have to add in order to filter by the timestamp.